# Javascript error without line number in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Why in this code snippet, the javascript error that is thrown doesn't contain the line number where the exception occurred?
In the doc [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) , it is written that there should be a member named `lineNumber`

Is there another way to get the line number in Chrome?

```
try {
    var a = {};
    a.b();
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.lineNumber);
    console.log(e);
}
```

Here is a repro: http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/a27ydh26/

Comment: There's an exclamation mark next to `lineNumber`. Hover over it and see what the message says.

Comment: Works great in Firefox; doesn't work in Chrome. This is the sort of thing I'd expect from an API whose behavior has not been standardized.

Comment: The Error API is not standardized, each browser implement it in a different way. take a look here: http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/

Answer (score 2):

As said [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/lineNumber) (also linked to the doc you posted) `lineNumber` is not standardized.

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

There is also a compatibility table that shows that Chrome doesn't support it. You shouldn't use it in production code, and it won't work in all browsers currently.